# Положение персонажей за объектами в 2д (вид сверху)

Tags: разработка-игр, 2d, godot

Начал изучать Godot. Rpg вид сверху. И нужен ваш совет, как мне сделать чтобы персонажи мобы прятались за деревьями домами. как это вообще реализуется в принципе (не только в годот).

Сейчас я использую area2d определенную площадь куда заходить персонаж и его индекс меняется. Но такой метод не очень, ведь нужно прописать для каждого объекта. А если менять индекс положение дерева то если например за деревом стоит объект то он перейдет на передний план.

Кто не понял о чем я вот видео - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Py-OA00AOFE

Comment: Конкретно с godot я не знаком, но в таких случаях для каждого слоя используется свой статичный z-индекс. С чего вы взяли, что он должен меняться? В вашем примере индексы должны располагаться в таком порядке: листва дерева > персонажи > ствол дерева (по высоте). Когда персонаж заходит под листву, её конечно можно делать прозрачной для удобства, но не менять индекс.

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf , вы чтот не так поняли , яж написал что мне интересно как реализуется переход персонажей за деревья и тд И что я незнаю как это грамотнее сделать.  В данный момент я использую площадь привязанную к дереву туда заходит персонаж - его индекс меняется тем самым он оказывается позади дерева(и этот метод для меня кажется плохим)

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf, а то есть надо поделить спрайт на части разные индексы, но я не совсем представляю как это будет выглядеть (и как мне сделать чтобы персонажи не ходили друг подругу, и вообще с отдельными частями это мне кажется так себе идея

Answer (score 2):

Все оказалось проще . В годот есть нод "Ysort" он сортирует объекты в зависимости от Y. Возможно в других движках также (годот мой первый ))

Comment: В других движках не так, в них есть специальный параметр у шейдеров - render queue.